# Appending element into list: the already appended elements change over time out of no reasons

Tags: python

A function that accepts a list of two elements as an argument is defined. I want to track how the list changes over time as it is iterated using the function by plotting it into the graph. But something strange happened. There is only one point plotted, so I tried to debug it by printing the lists, as shown in the following code:

```
from math import pi, sin, cos, tan
import numpy as np


alpha = pi/3
N = 10


def vmap(v):
    if v[0] >= 2*v[1]**0.5*tan(alpha)-(1-v[1])**0.5:
        v[0], v[1] = v[0] - 2*v[1]**0.5*tan(alpha), v[1]
    else:
        z = v[1]
        v[1] = -v[1]*(1+0.5*sin(4*alpha)*tan(alpha))-0.5*v[0]**2*sin(4*alpha)/tan(alpha) + v[0]*v[1]**0.5*sin(4*alpha) + 2*(cos(alpha))**2
        v[0] = -v[0] + (z**0.5 - v[1]**0.5)*tan(alpha)
    return v

v = [0.3, 0.5]

v_list = []
print(v)
v_list.append(v)
print(v_list)
print(vmap(v))
v_list.append(vmap(v))
print(v_list)
```

The output:

```
[0.3, 0.5]
[[0.3, 0.5]]
[0.12389232074709905, 0.21378826929126177]
[[-0.41955313380287024, 0.40078051892442046], [-0.41955313380287024, 0.40078051892442046]]
```

I do not understand what has happened. I appended `[0.3, 0.5]` into the empty list, the empty list became `[[0.3, 0.5]]` as expected. But as I appended `vmap([0.3, 0.5])` into the list, which is `[0.12389232074709905, 0.21378826929126177]`, the list does not yield the expected result of `[[0.3, 0.5], [0.12389232074709905, 0.21378826929126177]]`, but `[[-0.41955313380287024, 0.40078051892442046], [-0.41955313380287024, 0.40078051892442046]]` which appeared out of thin air. Why is it so?

Comment: Python doesn't create the implicit copies you're expecting. Read up on [how Python variables and objects work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: As a general rule, either mutate the argument and return `None` or return a new object leaving the argument unchanged. Don't mutate *and* return the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at your code: you have appended `v` twice to v_list.  This is not two separate lists, but the same list, twice.  Both elements of `v_list` are references to `v`: when you change `v`, the value of each reference changes.

Change this by appending a *copy* of `v`, rather than your ever-changing variable:

```
from copy import copy
...
v_list.append(copy(v))
print(v_list)
print(vmap(v))
v_list.append(copy(vmap(v)))
print(v_list)
```

Output:

```
[0.3, 0.5]
[[0.3, 0.5]]
[0.12389232074709916, 0.2137882692912617]
[[0.3, 0.5], [-0.41955313380287046, 0.40078051892442046]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing `v` inside the call to `vmap`. When you add `v` to `v_list`, a *reference* to `v` is added. When you pass `v` to the function `vmap`, you're operating on the same object. Any changes you make to it inside the function are reflected after the function call returns.

Answer (score 0):

@Sato, Here's what you should normally do:

```
v = [0.3, 0.5]

v_list = []
print(v)
v_list.append(v)
print(v_list)
print(vmap(v))
v_list.append(v)  #Note that the function vmap modifies v
print(v_list)
```